# problem with z-index with positioned tags

Tags: html, css, z-index

I can't figure out why the z-index set to different element doesn't work as expected.

Is there someone that could explain me why the **img** with *CC class* is overlying the other two, even if it has a lower z-index?

Looking to the theory, the positioned object should have to work with z-index, but in this case they don't; I tried to chenge the integers of the z-.indexes, and also I added the display: block to them, but they still not follow the supposed rules.

```css
.slideshow {
  opacity: 1;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  width: var(--width);
  height: 80%;
  margin: 2vh auto;
  /* margin: 4vh auto; */
}

.slideshow__inner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slideshow__inner:not(.slideshow__inner--back, .slideshow__inner--front) {
  transform: scale(.95);
}

.slideshow__inner img {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0.1px);
}

.slideshow__inner img.AA {
  z-index: 4;
}

.slideshow__inner img.BB {
  top: 15%;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 15%;
}

.slideshow__inner img.CC {
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow__inner">
    <img class="AA" src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/05/03/04/34/marseille-7170837_960_720.jpg'></img>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow__inner">
    <img class="BB" src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/04/06/26/wadi-rum-1120371_960_720.jpg'></img>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow__inner active">
    <img class="CC" src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/21/20/49/road-7148369_960_720.jpg'></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that images are self-closing, so there is no `</img>`

Comment: the scale transform is creating a stacking context

Comment: Yes, I worked around a lot yesterday to solve the problem changing the tags, and the img closing remained. It looks like an error of amateur... sorry for that! In any case, this correction doen't have an influence on the problem.

Comment: Ok, @TemaniAfif, this looks like the right suggestion. I'll try further, but it seems the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).
>
> from https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.php

So you need to set the position css attribute to your image classes. I would try `position: relative` in your case.

Comment: Well, I need the absolute position in this case; I colud try to reconsider the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example here to test https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/0oh4rpeq/

I have removed the  closing tags as per the comment. I have also added absolute urls for each image.

And added opacity 0.5 to the images, I think this is doing what your css is suggesting.

CSS is identical but I added this:

```
img  {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```css
.slideshow {
  opacity: 1;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  width: var(--width);
  height: 80%;
  margin: 2vh auto;
  /* margin: 4vh auto; */
}

.slideshow__inner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slideshow__inner:not(.slideshow__inner--back, .slideshow__inner--front) {
  transform: scale(.95);
}

.slideshow__inner img {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0.1px);
}

.slideshow__inner img.AA {
  z-index: 4;
}

.slideshow__inner img.BB {
  top: 15%;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 15%;
}

.slideshow__inner img.CC {
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
}

img  {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow__inner">
    <img class="AA" src='https://dummyimage.com/600x425'>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow__inner">
    <img class="BB" src='https://dummyimage.com/500x325'>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow__inner active">
    <img class="CC" src='https://dummyimage.com/200x325'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Done. But I always maintain my jsfiddles ;)

Comment: Sure, but why have to lave SO when I can just stay here and click RUN while I read your comments?